# Use PowerShell to write Data direct to OMS

Tags: powershell, azure, operations, oms

I'd like to write my custom data direct to our Microsoft Azure OMS using powershell. Does anyone know how this is possible?

There's alot of information about configuring instances, adding new datasources, or querying the data using Azure​RM.​Operational​Insights:

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/privatecloud/2016/04/05/using-the-oms-search-api-with-native-powershell-cmdlets/

https://learn.microsoft.com/de-ch/powershell/module/azurerm.operationalinsights/?view=azurermps-4.0.0

Has anyone found a way to directly write data to OMS instead of storing it in a log-file and then use custom-log-import? I know this is possible, i saw it in a keynote, but cannot find any information about this.

Thank you for your Inputs!

Comment: Based on my knowledge, it is not possible. Please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/log-analytics/log-analytics-data-sources-custom-logs).

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick - writing to Log Analytics:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/log-analytics/log-analytics-data-collector-api#sample-requests

Really not much to add, it's a copy/paste process. Entries will show using the type you define in $LogType appended with '_CL' because you essentially create a Custom Log entry.